# How do I count the number of identical characters in a string by position using python?

Tags: python, string

For example:

```
String 1: AGGCCT
          || | |
String 2: AGCCAT
```

These two strings are identical at 4 positions, so the function I want would return 4.

Is there a clever (i.e., fast) method for doing this, other than the obvious method of iterating through both strings at the same time?

Thanks!
Uri

Comment: Please post the code you have.  If you iterate by position, it's one pass through both strings.  What's wrong with that?  Please post your code so we can comment on it.

Comment: For loops are slow in python.  Really, I am asking if there is some built-in function (implemented in C) that I can use to make this very fast.  Is this incorrect?  (And this is not a homework assignment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think any "clever" trick beats the obvious approach, if it's well executed:

```
sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(s1, s2))
```

Or, if the use of booleans for arithmetic irks you,

```
sum(1 for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(s1, s2) if c1 == c2)
```

Comment: Those `[ACGT]+` strings can be very long. `zip(...)` is a list. Consider using `itertools.izip`.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the hint. I'm constantly forgetting that Python 2 uses lists instead of iterator in many built-ins. Fixed.

Comment: @S.Lott he wanted the count of identical chars; `all()` would return `False`.

Comment: @S.Lott: What you wrote is a vary baroque version of `s1 == s2`

Answer (score 1):

Though I prefer delnan's generator expression, this works as well:

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> from operator import eq
>>> sum(imap(eq, 'abcde', 'aacce'))
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for better performance, I suspect it will be hard to beat numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.frombuffer(s1, dtype=np.byte)
a2 = np.frombuffer(s2, dtype=np.byte)
print (a1==a2).sum()
```

On my system, this runs about 10x faster than using itertools.